Page pull-down refresh triggers scroll-snap on mobile devices
I have an issue with one of my scroll-snap implementations.
The problem is, that when you pull down the web page on a mobile device to refresh it, this "overscroll" or better to say bounce of the browser triggers a scroll-snap. That means that when you are on top of the page and you pull it down to refresh it, it immediately jumps to the 2. section.
Here is the code:


/*----------------------------------- Global styling -----------------------------------*/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;;
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}

#outer_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content_section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.content_section:nth-child(1) {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7) url("../Media/images/hero_image-1_P576.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.content_section:nth-child(2) {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4) url("../Media/images/hero_image-2_P576.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.content_section:nth-child(3) {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4) url("../Media/images/hero_image-3_P576.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.small_text {
    font-size: .6rem;
}

.medium_text {
    font-size: .8rem;
}

.large_text {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.headline {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

/* ------------------------ Section 1 formating ------------------------ */

#inner_wrapper-1 {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#layout-1 {
    width: 100%;
}

/* ------------------------ Section 2 formating ------------------------ */

#inner_wrapper-2 {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#layout-2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


/* ------------------------ Section 3 formating ------------------------ */

#inner_wrapper-3 {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#layout-3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="de">

<!------------------------------ Head section ------------------------------>

    <head>
        <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="lorem ipsum"/>
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <meta name="copyright" content="" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    </head>
    
<!------------------------------ Body section ------------------------------>
    
    <body>

        <div class="content-wrapper" id="outer_wrapper">
        
            <div class="content_section" id="content_section-1">
                <div class="content-wrapper" id="inner_wrapper-1">
                    <div class="layout" id="layout-1">
                        <p>Section 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content_section" id="content_section-2">
                <div class="content-wrapper" id="inner_wrapper-2">
                    <div class="layout" id="layout-2">
                        <p>Section 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content_section" id="content_section-3">
                <div class="content-wrapper" id="inner_wrapper-3">
                    <div class="layout" id="layout-3">
                        <p>Section 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>

    </body>
</html>



Does anyone know what is causing this behaviour or how to prevent it?
Thank you in advance for your support
Regards

Does no-one have an idea regarding this topic?
